# Should I use "can" or 'may"

Tags: can-may

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Can/may/will you help me with this?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4919/can-may-will-you-help-me-with-this)

Here is the sentence:

```
If you like you {can|may} translate this text to English.
```

What word should I use here and why.

Comment: If you have time, you would be very welcome to translate this text to English

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as if you're giving permission. In a very formal or legal (copyright is involved and the translation isn't merely an academic exercise but will be published somewhere public) situation, *may* is reasonable, but most native speakers of American English would use *can* to indicate *permission* rather than saying that they think you *are able* (**can**) to do the translation.

> If **you'd like (to)**, you **may** translate this text to English.  [formal]
>   If **you'd like (to)**, you **can** translate this text to English.  [informal]

It's context dependent: What's the occasion and who are you speaking to and why?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The context of the text is that I'm proposing to translate the text. With this sentence I want to say "If you like and have time and wish to, then you {can|may} translate this text".